# Trim column length to 6 characters

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file with over 30 columns and I want to trim the length of let's say 9th column to 6 characters (using shell).
Not able to get a good solution.
Please help!

Comment: There is no appropriate tool AFAIK in standard shell utilities. Unless you are using something more elaborated than /bin/sh, think using awk or perl.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` would be an excellent choice here. For example lets say we need to trim the first column (`$1`) to six characters, we can write something like

```
awk '{$1 = gensub(/^(......).*$/, "\\1", $1)}1'
```

**Test**

```
$ echo 'helloworld' | awk '{$1 = gensub(/^(......).*$/, "\\1", $1)}1'
hellow
```

**What it does**

- [`gensub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) does a regular expression substitute.

  - `/^(......).*$/` Matches 6 characters and captures them in `\1`, if you note you could see 6 dots in the `()`.
  - `\\1`  replace the entire column content with the captured 6 characters.
- `1` Always evaluates to true, `awk` takes the default action to print the entire record.

Comment: Note that `gensub` is a GNU awk feature.

Comment: Thanks! Where do I give my file name?

Comment: @user1855888 at the end of the script. eg like `$ awk {some comands}' filename`

Comment: I can't use to truncate and replace the 9th column. Even when I replace $1 with $9.
It's in fact truncating the first column to 6 characters and then adding that to the end of the 30th column.

Comment: How you are writing the `gensub` ?

Comment: I suspect that you are having a different field separator, by default it is space. If you are having different one use `-F` option to specify the separator. For example if it is `,`, then `-F,`